# Can't create multiple IPv6 tunnels

Tags: linux, routing, ipv6, tunnel

I am trying to create two IPv6 BGP tunnels with two providers (HE.net and  Securebit AG). system does not allows to create more than one, whatever the connection I created first works fine. each ISP connections are configured to port forward to my router box

I've used these commands to bring up 1 st connection and it works fine

```
ifconfig sit0 up
ifconfig sit0 inet6 tunnel ::216.YYY.YYY.YYY
ifconfig sit1 up
ifconfig sit1 inet6 add YYYY:YYYY:YYYY:e1::2/64
```

getting these errors when try to bring up 2nd connection

```
ifconfig sit2 up
sit2: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

ifconfig sit2 inet6 tunnel ::80.XXX.XXX.XXX
SIOGIFINDEX: No such device

ifconfig sit3 up
sit3: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

ifconfig sit3 inet6 add XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:15b::2/64
SIOGIFINDEX: No such device
```

my Ipv4 routing table as follows and  kernel version is `4.9.35`

```
route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
default         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    203    0        0 eth1
default         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    209    0        0 eth2
default         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    300    0        0 eth2
80.XXX.XXX.0    192.168.8.1     255.255.240.0   UG    0      0        0 eth2
94.XXX.XXX.0    192.168.8.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth2
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     204    0        0 docker0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     206    0        0 vethef89bf3
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.8.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     203    0        0 eth1
192.168.8.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     209    0        0 eth2
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
216.YY.YY.0     192.168.1.1     255.255.240.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

do you have any clue on this ? Thanks

Comment: Why does your "first connection" consist of _two_ interfaces?

Comment: @grawity I've used default configuration for linux-net-tools provided by he.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your kernel version is new enough that you should be using *iproute2* instead of the 2.4-era tools.

Ignore sit0; explicitly create a new interface for every connection:

```
ip link add henet type sit local 192.168.1.x remote 216.66.84.y ttl 64
ip addr add 2001:470:yyyy::2/64 dev henet
ip link set henet up

ip link add securebit type sit local 192.168.1.x remote 80.y.y.y ttl 64
ip addr add XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:15b::2/64 dev securebit
ip link set securebit up
```

Alternatively, if your version of `ip link add` does not yet support sit tunnels:

```
ip tunnel add henet mode sit local 192.168.1.x remote 216.66.84.y ttl 64
ip addr add...
```

Note how each tunnel consists of just one interface in this model, unlike the old system with sit0 having magic properties.

Comment: Thanks grawith, I've updated my configurations to use iproute2 now I can create second interlace but still I can't reach my second BGP neighbor using ping6 and but I can see some activity via `tcpdump` and it's show some checksum mismatch and I believe it's a different  issue now I am facing